# Display only certain amount of wordpress comments

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Im trying to figure out how to in wordpress display only first two comments and hide rest and add button that reveal all these hidden messages if needed. Pagination give me only two msg per page and thats not im looking for. Can someone give me an idea how I can this achieve or point me to articles about this?

Thanks

Comment: not getting your point please explain properly

Comment: In standard behaviour WP showing all comments, and offer only pagination to break them if there is more. Sorry I wrote messages instead comments. I got idea from smashing mag. This is I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// This function hide comments if is there more than two and add show more button      
 function fds_comments () {
        var commentWrap = document.getElementById('comment-list');
        var commentChilderns = commentWrap.children;
        for (var i = 2; i < commentChilderns.length; i++) {
            commentChilderns[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        commentWrap.innerHTML = commentWrap.innerHTML + "<button id='more-comments' onclick='fds_all_comments()'type='button' >Show all comments</button>";
    }

//This function reveal all comments (used on SHOW MORE btn)
    function fds_all_comments(){
        var commentWrap = document.getElementById('comment-list');
        var commentChilderns = commentWrap.children;
        for (var i = 0; i < commentChilderns.length; i++) {
            commentChilderns[i].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
// problem: comments hidden after submit
// solved: This additional code reveal comments after SUBMIT

window.onload = function() {
    var reloading = sessionStorage.getItem("reloading");
    if (reloading) {
        sessionStorage.removeItem("reloading");
        fds_all_comments();
    }
}

// function used on SUBMIT button
function fds_all_on_submit(){
    sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", "true");
    document.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: I have came with this solution for now but if there will be better way how to do it please let me know

Comment: I have added some code to solve problem of hidden comments after submit

Answer (score 0):

here is a plugin that should do the job: https://wordpress.org/plugins/comment-load-more/

It is a bit outdated (3 years ago) so you should check if the code is still valid and compatible.

In " Settings > Comment Load" you should be able to set the number of desired comments to show first.

Indeed, in this guide - http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-lazy-load-comments-in-wordpress/ - you will find how to lazy load all comments. Probably, with some modification, you can adapt it to your need as well.

Cheers!

Comment: thanks I'll look on these sources. Because I almost finished theme I do for my self I prefer to do it with own code than plugin because of full control over results. I there will be other sources or ideas please post them also.

Comment: I didn't use any of these plugins but thank you fast response anyway. When I will find solution I will share it here, But It take some time. In meantime I'm still looking for How to ...